# Deploying [different-project-folder] instead of selected folder [current-project-folder]. Use "appService.deploySubpath" to change this behavior

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, web-deployment

I have two projects I'm working on for two separate **Web Apps** on **Microsoft Azure** under the same subscription. The first **Web App** project works fine, but for some reason when I try to deploy my new project to the other **Web App**, **VSCode** keeps telling me:

`Deploying [first-project-folder] instead of selected folder [current-project-folder]. Use "appService.deploySubpath" to change this behavior.`

Even when I change this setting to point to the correct project folder, it does the same thing. Nothing changes. I'm using the **Azure App Service** extension in **VSCode** on **Windows 10**.

Comment: Hello, i have the same problem. How did you solve it please ?

Comment: Hello, i would like to know how you did solve your problem please ? i am facing the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and it was because I was changing the `deploySubpath` in the wrong `settings.json` file. I changed the one in the directory I was trying to deploy and it didn't work.

Try changing `settings.json` under the root `\.vscode`.

Comment: Oooh. Is it because I have both projects in the same working directory then? Can I just move that folder to the root project folder it's for and create another one in the newer project folder? Or do I need to have each project as a separate working directory?

Comment: Can you add a sample? What in detail do you mean with "changing under the root"?

Comment: Oh man, a year later. Sorry. The core of my issue was my misunderstanding of workspace folders in VSCode. From what I've learned, each root folder in the workspace explorer is considered the root of a single project. I had several projects at the time under a single root folder. I had the deployment settings for that root folder set as one of my earlier projects. Then I wanted to deploy a later project to Azure but ran into this problem.